# How do I create a multiprocessed socket server?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-sockets

I'm working on a socket server for this bot I'm building. My idea is to have multiple clients handle certain tasks. One observer, a calculator, and a trader. I want these to communicate with each other by creating a socket server.

I'm using multiprocessing for the clients, since some will be working with blocking code. I created a simple server function and a client object. They worked fine when I ran them separately, but not when I ran them from a main script. It would be wonderful if any of you could take a look!

Thanks in advance <3

Maarten

```py
    #server 
    import socket

    class Server:
        def __init__(self, host, port, listen):
            self.addr = (host, port)
            self.listen = listen

        def start(self):
            self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.s.bind(self.addr)
            self.s.listen(self.listen)
            print('Listening..')

        def main(self):
            self.start()
            
            conn, addr = self.s.accept()
            print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
            msg_received = 0

            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break;
                msg_received += 1
                print(msg_received)
            s.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        server = Server('localhost',8008, 1)
        server.main()
```

- 

```py
      #client
    import socket
    import time

    class Client:
        def __init__(self, host, port):
            self.addr = (host, port)

        def main(self):
            self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.s.connect(self.addr)
            print('Connected to host!')
            msg = b'koekjes'

            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                self.s.send(msg)
                print('Sent cookies!')
            self.s.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        c = Client('localhost', 8008)
        c.main()
```

- 

```py
    #main-script
    from multiprocessing import Process

    from server import Server
    from client import Client

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        s = Server('localhost', 8007, 1)
        c = Client('localhost', 8007)
        try:
            print('creating process')
            Process(target=s.main, daemon=True).start()
            Process(target=c.main, daemon=True).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print('\n' + e + '\n')
            c.stop()
            s.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a check whether modules are being run directly or being imported:

```
# server.py
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

```
# client.py
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Client('localhost', 8008)
    c.main()
```

Comment: I've now created two classes (server and client) and they work perfectly, but I'd would like to run these two processes (and those to follow) from the same script. Would you happen to know a way to achieve this result?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I made some changes. Hopefully, I did it correctly. I made sure that both classes work separately again, but I still can't get them to work from a main script. It would be wonderful if you could take another look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by using examples from this question: [ZeroMQ hangs in a python multiprocessing class/object solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257579/zeromq-hangs-in-a-python-multiprocessing-class-object-solution)

This code works perfectly:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import socket
import time


class Base(Process):
    """
    Inherit from Process
    """
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.address = (host, port)
        

class Server(Base):   
    def run(self):
        print('running server')
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(self.address)
        self.s.listen(1)
        print('listening..')
        conn, addr = self.s.accept()
        msg_received = 0

        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break;
            msg_received +=1
            print(msg_received)
        self.s.close()
        


class Client(Base):
    def run(self):
        print('running client')
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect(self.address)
        msg = b'cookies'

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.s.send(msg)
            print('Sent cookies!')
        self.s.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 8008
    
    s = Server(host, port)
    c = Client(host, port)
    print('both objects created')
    s.start()
    c.start()
```